# How to get the schema of a Bigquery table via a Java program?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Am using DataFlow 2.0/Apache Beam as the framework to read data from BigQuery and write to a SQL database. Would like to read the schema definition from BigQuery and then create an equivalent table in the SQL definition.

What is the Java API to get the BigQuery schema definition?

The docs only talk about reading the data but not the metadata.

Thanks
-ravi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [BigQuery Java client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java). The schema of a table can be accessed via `bigQuery.getTable(datasetId, tableId).getDefinition().getSchema()`.

Comment: The BigQuery Java client library seems to have a problem with DataFlow, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/607#issuecomment-335651361 its there a workaround, maybe using the BigqueryIO library ?

Comment: Apparently it's not the only comment mentioning that issue https://github.com/spotify/scio/issues/951#issuecomment-348017824